# How to include external css file only for my custom vue component?

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, vue-component

I am building a vue js component and want to upload into npm.

The problem is :

When i am importing any 3rd party css cdn in my component then it is getting applied to whole html instead of only to my component.

Does any one one know how can i import only for my component, so that if user installs my package and use it then css should be applicable only to this component rather than applying to whole application which may break user's css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should use `scoped` attribute https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html

Comment: yes but this works only when i have few classes, i want to import whole bootstrap css library

Answer (score 0):

you can Scoped CSS, When a  tag has the scoped attribute, its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only, example :

```
<template>
  <div class="example">hi</div>
</template>
<style scoped>
 @import url;

.example {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're building an npm package that relies on other large packages like Bootstrap or any other CSS/JS frameworks, you should make sure that it doesn't get included with your plugin. 
You should let the user import those frameworks themselves and your component should use that imported package.

To do so, you should remove such packages from your `dependencies` in `package.json` while building. Also, you should mention in your plugin documentation about the dependencies your plugin relies on.

For your case, if you absolutely need to include CSS with your package, only import the require SCSS files from Bootstrap in Scoped CSS like this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "bootstrap/required-files"
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Harsh, Thanks for reply, but when i am including using @import inside scoped, then no css is getting applied when using that component after styling.
do i need to configure something in vue.config.js -> earlier i was doing module.exports = {
    css: {
        extract: false
    }
}

but this was adding css globaly

Comment: Are you importing CSS from CDN within component?